Classification of intervals in time series data of multiple instances
I have a problem that I am trying to frame. I have signal data from ECG (a classic signal over time data). A close example here: https://github.com/jjongjjong/ECG_segmentation_1DUnet
I am basically interested in identifying segments in the ECG data (t-wave, QRS ..etc).
So the data is from multiple patients (repeated measures or independent patients) and each patient has his own meta data. The output is a one-hot encoded x-axis (time) indicating the intervals to be classified (simpler than the data in the previous link)
What I was thinking I will need a neural net with simple layer or two of convolution, then a recurrent layers or transformer layers. What I have come to know that adding a state-keeping layers is going to be a good idea for this problem but seem difficult to implement.
So how can I implement a NN with patient characteristics to get output of interest?
